# How can I stream pdf file of size upto (1 GB) from a server to client in a downloadable form in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, stream, download

I have a pdf file (could be upto couple of GBs) on a server. I want to send it to client so that the client can download it on his local machine. I guess I need to use Stream class in C# to get the data from the web server. But I am not sure if the Stream class has limitation on the file size it can stream?

Also once I have the data stream, how can I send it to Client so that he can download that on his local machine? Can we do that in C#? Or in other words, how can I convert this data stream into a downloadable file?

Comment: What are you using on the server? if MVC - you should just be able to use return File(path); from an ActionMethod

Comment: Yeah, I am using MVC. Sorry,I don't understand what to return. Is it the url of the file on server? And should I return that as an ActionResult?

Comment: There is a size limit. But it is huge, many TBs or much more. I cannot remember clearly.

Comment: @Ryan:That would be good for me.

Comment: You can send this pdf async using WebApi. Check this link: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted, that if you're using a web server to send the file, you won't likely need to code anything for it, the web server has the functionality built in.

The `Stream` class supports buffering which is what you'll need to use.  Here is a simple example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // 1 KB buffer
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.pdf"))
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) // output the stream into memory, this is what you'll want to change for your purposes
{
    int read;
    while((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the issue. I don't want to use Memory Stream because of size limits. And I don't how else can I send the stream data to client so that he can download it.

Comment: I used `MemoryStream` just as an example.  You'll want to look up `NetworkStream` or another similar `Stream`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This answer is mostly about client side code downloading file from web.

If you need server side code - ASP.Net MVC have perfect method for it already - [Controller.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492492%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

`Stream` class have no limitations on size of the data (and there are infinite streams like `NetworkStream`). Individual implementations may have restrictions on size cased by internal details (i.e. `MemoryStream` limited by maximum size of single managed memory block - just under 2GB)

Files under 2GB don't require any special coding at all, bigger sizes need slightly more care due to integer overflows and restriction on maximum size of single block of managed memory (i.e. if attempting to save 4GB into `MemoryStream`).

In most cases existing classes (like `FileStream`) and methods (like `Stream.CopyTo`) should be enough to deal with large files.

Also check if existing classes like [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is enough for you:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
```

Comment: I cannot expose the url. On my web server, I will get the file from a data server which is then sent to client. `WebClient.DownloadFile` takes the URL. Is there any other way to send large files to client form my web server. Also I cannot store the whole file on my webserver from data server. I have to do something like chunk streaming which I am not sure how to do.